# ImageMagick not rendering all Unicode characters

Tags: linux, unicode, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to render small single character images with ImageMagick.

I'm calling it like this:

```
echo -n "\u1407" | convert -background black -fill white \
  -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
  -pointsize 12 label:@- gif:1407.gif
```

When I just echo on my terminal, that has this font (DejaVu-Sans-Mono) set, I see this triangle: `ᐇ` but in the GIF is just a question mark. No special markings, just a question mark. It works for some other characters, like these special parens: `⟨⟩` at `27e8` and `27e9`, but the next pair isn't working again.

What do I need to do to enable all characters that the font supplies? Did I set the wrong font?

My distribution is LMDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with bash & unicode, I always need to step back, and do an extra step.

```
echo -n ᐇ | hexdump
```

This gives me the correct hex-triplet

```
0000000 e1 90 87
```

So then my unicode escape sequence in bash would be..

```
echo -ne "\xE1\x90\x87"
```

*(omitting the 0x0A which is the line-feed)*

```
echo -ne "\xE1\x90\x87" | convert -background black -fill white \
  -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf \
  -pointsize 12 label:@- gif:1407.gif
```

However this produces the following image [image: character missing], as the character is not apart of the **DejaVu Sans Mono** set, but it is apart of the **DejaVu Sans**.

```
echo -ne "\xE1\x90\x87" | convert -background black -fill white \
  -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf \
  -pointsize 12 label:@- gif:1407.gif
```

[image: works]

[Additional info](http://www.scarfboy.com/coding/unicode-tool?s=U%2B1407) about ᐇ

There could be a perfectly valid reason why this glyph is not included. A polite thing would be to reach out to the DejaVu team, and inquire if this is a bug, or included elsewhere. [IRC](http://irc://irc.freenode.org/dejavu) & [Mailing lists](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Mailing_list) are a good start.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. You can prevent `echo` from printing a "\n" with the `-n` flag (as in my answer). I don't know if the `\u` escape is `zsh`-specific, but echo definitely passes the right input to convert. My guess would be that there is some kind of fallback mechanism in place that `convert` doesn't use. It gets a little bit strange in the higher planes: The graphemes take up more than one character width. `echo "\u33D6\n\u33D6\e[2GWow"` prints ㏖ and then again on the next line, but starts to write "Wow" in the middle (I moved the cursor to position 2 in between).

Comment: Short Q: Do you know a way to determine (***fast***) if a given character (like the `ᐇ` one here) is covered by a font file or not? (I know ways to determine it in an intricate, longwinded, indirect way...) Bonus points for mentioning a command line tool doing in a very simple way that I'm not aware of yet...

Comment: @KurtPfeifle I think FontConfig is what your looking for. I'm not familiar, but check the man pages for `fc-cat`, `fc-match`, `fc-query`, `fc-scan` & etc. I half remember one of them can print out ASCII table, if not list unicode support.

Comment: Oh, I've dabbled with `fc-*`-commands in the past. They're mostly ugly to handle... :-( See also this: http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/fontconfig/2013-September/004915.html (My currently preferred (indirect) way is to dump the CMAP table of a font with `ttx` like this: `ttx -t cmap -d . /path/to/fontfile`, then open file `./fontfile.ttx`...)

Comment: Ah, and I forgot to say: I didn't discover any option to get an `fc-*`.command to enumerate all glyphs and associated character names contained in a font file...

Comment: Since my question is directed for image magick, I'll accept it. I realized that I'll need a font rendering tool, like `pango-view`